# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component with Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, formik

I am so stuck on what to do. The full error is:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function. at Formik (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:42765:19)

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Formik, Field } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import Button from "../../components/UI/Forms/Button";
import Heading from "../../components/UI/Headings/Headings";
import Message from "../../components/UI/Messages/Message";
import Modal from "../../components/UI/Modal/Modal";
import Input from "../../components/UI/Forms/Input";
import { StyledForm } from "../../components/styles/Wrappers";

import * as actions from "../../store/actions";

const ButtonsWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  justify-content: space-around;
`;
const MessageWrapper = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0 rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 3rem;
`;

const ProjectSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  project: Yup.string()
    .required("The project is required.")
    .min(2, "Too short."),
});

const InputProject = ({
  project,
  addProject,
  loading,
  error,
  opened,
  close,
  editProject,
}) => {
  const loadingText = project ? "Editing..." : "Adding...";

  console.log(project);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Modal opened={opened} close={close}>
        <Heading noMargin size="h1" color="white">
          {project ? "Edit your project" : "Add your new Project"}
        </Heading>
        <Heading bold size="h4" color="white">
          {project ? "Change your project here" : "Type your project here"}
        </Heading>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            project: project ? project.name : "",
          }}
          validationSchema={ProjectSchema}
          onSubmit={async (values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
            // send our project
            const res = project
              ? await editProject(project.id, values)
              : await addProject(values);
            setSubmitting(false);
            if (res) {
              close();
            }
            resetForm();
          }}
        >
          {({ values, handleChange, isSubmitting, isValid, resetForm }) => (
            <StyledForm>
              <Field
                type="text"
                name="project"
                placeholder={project ? project.name : "Write your project..."}
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={values.project}
                component={Input}
              />
              <ButtonsWrapper>
                <Button
                  contain
                  color="main"
                  type="submit"
                  disabled={!isValid || isSubmitting}
                  loading={loading ? loadingText : null}
                >
                  {project ? "Edit Project" : "Add Project"}
                </Button>
                <Button
                  type="button"
                  color="red"
                  contain
                  onClick={() => {
                    close();
                    resetForm();
                  }}
                >
                  Cancel
                </Button>
              </ButtonsWrapper>
              <MessageWrapper>
                <Message error show={error}>
                  {error}
                </Message>
              </MessageWrapper>
            </StyledForm>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </Modal>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ projects }) => ({
  loading: projects.loading,
  error: projects.error,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  addProject: actions.addProject,
  editProject: actions.editProject,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InputProject);
```

Comment: Is the `if (res) close();` call closing the modal and unmounting the form before `resetForm();` occurs? Does the form need to be reset at this time?

Comment: @DrewReese the close() and the resetForm() do not seem to be the issue as I tried removing them at one point to troubleshoot and it had no effect on the problem

Comment: Ok, just a guess from the limited snippet you provided. I was just looking for anything that looked like it may result in an enqueued state update. Do you know what component is complaining about the update after mounting? Can you provide reproduction steps, i.e. what are you doing that causes the issue?

Comment: @DrewReese it says formik is complaining. So this form is a duel add/edit form where based off if a project was passed, it either creates a new one or edits an old one. I have no issues creating a new one but when I go to edit it gives me that error

Comment: So it seems calling `editProject` in `onSubmit` allows the issue to occur? Can you include that action creator code and provide an overview of how this form works and toggling between the two "modes"? Walk through what happens from the point a user clicks the submit button up to the action completes?